# Retrieving all e-mails on exchange server

Tags: exchange-server

Is there any way to retrieve the e-mail subject, date received, e-mail sender & e-mail recipient of ALL e-mails on an outlook server and put it into an Excel file?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you might be able to find something if you search for the same thing for IMAP or POP.  Exchange supports those protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EWS Managed API to collect everything from Exchange mailbox: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx